# tbody vertical scroll with sticky column

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a sticky column (see jsfiddle below). But I´m trying to have a vertical scroll just on the table body so the headers are always visible and the height of tbody should be fixed. How can I do this?

```css
        body {
          font: 16px Calibri;
        }
        
        table {
          border-collapse: separate;
          border-top: 3px solid grey;
        }
        
        td,th {
          margin: 0;
          border: 3px solid grey;
          border-top-width: 0px;
          white-space: nowrap;
        }
        
        div {
          width: 600px;
          overflow-x: scroll;
          margin-left: 5em;
          overflow-y: visible;
          padding-bottom: 1px;
        }
        
        .headcol {
          position: absolute;
          width: 5em;
          left: 0;
          top: auto;
          border-right: 0px none black;
          border-top-width: 3px;
          /*only relevant for first row*/
          margin-top: -3px;
          /*compensate for top border*/
        }
        
        .long {
          background: yellow;
          letter-spacing: 1em;
        }
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">sticky col</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="headcol">1</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="headcol">2</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="headcol">3</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="headcol">4</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="headcol">5</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="headcol">6</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="headcol">7</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="headcol">8</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="headcol">9</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The end result should be similar to this:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/frozen-columns

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the position to fixed of the cell that you would like to remain fixed during vertical scroll.

```
.headcol {
position:fixed;
}
```